# drupal load node in edit mode via link including attribute to change publishing option to published? drupal_goto

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Is it possible to load a node in edit mode and set the **publishing option** to published?

```
drupal_goto("node/$node->nid/edit");
```

so the user doesn't has to set the option manually and only gets saved as published once the user clicks save (node is set to not published).

I want to replace the programmatic approach as it also saves it before edit mode

```
$node->status = NODE_PUBLISHED;
node_save($node);
```

FYI "**Publishing options**" field

```
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-status">
<input type="checkbox" id="edit-status" name="status" value="1" class="form-checkbox">  
<label class="option" for="edit-status">Published </label>
```

Comment: I tried [Prepopulate](https://www.drupal.org/project/prepopulate) module for **passing parameters** in the url, but I think it only works with new nodes, not editing existing ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x) to change the form:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    // if ($form_id == 'TYPE_node_form') {
        $form['options']['status']['#default_value'] = 1;
    // }
}
```

So, the publishing option will be checked.

**Or** :

You can use the [`hook_node_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7.x) to change the node properties (when submitted):

```
function MYMODULE_node_presave($node) {
    $node->status = NODE_PUBLISHED;
}
```

This will cause to set the node to published even if the publishing option is not checked.

---

**Edit:** After reading the comments, I suggest you to use another behavior. You could append `?from-email` into you `drupal_goto()`, then in the `hook_form_alter()`, prepend a custom submit, then, in the `hook_node_presave()`, compare the values of the original node and the posted values, and force the `status` if a change is detected :

1. When you come from the email, change your `drupal_goto()` to:

   ```
   drupal_goto("node/$node->nid/edit", ['query' => ['from-email' => 1]]);
   ```
2. In your `hook_form_alter()`, check if the URL contains `from-email`, add a custom handler:

   ```
   function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
       if (isset($_GET['from-email'])) {
           // add at the first place to the list of handlers:
           array_unshift($form['actions']['submit']['#submit'], 'MODULE_my_custom_submit_handler') ;
       }
   }
   ```
3. The custom handler:

   ```
   function MYMODULE_my_custom_submit_handler($form, &$form_state) {

       $nid = $form_state['values']['nid'];
       $node = node_load($nid);

       // to debug:
       // var_dump($form_state['values'], $node);die;

       // check diff
       $to_publish = false ;
       if ($node->title != $form_state['values']['title']) $to_publish = true;
       if ($node->body['und'][0]['value'] != $form_state['values']['body']['und'][0]['value']) $to_publish = true ;
       // and so on...

       if ($to_publish) {
           // force the status to 1.
           $form_state['values']['status'] = 1;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Great thanks @Syscall. The module would apply though to all nodes rather then just individual ones that I'm loading with drupal_goto, inside an email.

Any way I can set that for partical ones (in my email) so that other nodes won't be effected in edit mode?

Comment: Preferably I want that when the user gets an email with link to edit a node which is unpublished, that they can view the content and if they change content and save it it will be as published, not having to manually set that option as well as I would have to remind them to do so, but if they just view the node in edit mode and never save it thus it remains unpublished.

Comment: @Markus I understand your need. I've updated the answer with another way with a combination of hook_form_alter and hook_node_presave. Hope it make sense.

Comment: Thanks @Syscall. I tried that but didn't work yet.
I put hook_form_alter and custom handler into a module which is activated and hope this is correct. But when I open the node edit link which already shows the new url ie. "node/264/edit?from-email=1" the publishing option is not pre-selected. 
Not sure why the custom handler has the **if-condition** for both title and body, should there not be a condition relating to the "publishing option" checkbox? 
FYI I updated my question with the field code. Do I need to utilise this?

Comment: I can see in devel that the object for the publishing option is called **"status"**. I already tried `if ($node->status!= $form_state['values']['status']) $to_publish = true;`

Comment: I put a `print "hello";` into form_alter and since it didn't print I take it's not being triggered, even though I can see in the console the GET parameter "from-email:1" is there.

Comment: @Markus Did you clear your Drupal cache? The hooks list is in cache because Drupal didn't check anytime for hook functions.

Comment: ok it showed, actually it printed it twice, which I did not expect. I also tried placing it into the custom handler instead (inside that module) which didn't appear hence suspecting the handler might not run?

I checked with dpm($form) in form_alter and can see actions>submit>#submit showing `0  MYMODULE_my_custom_submit_handler`

Comment: just to clarify, with the custom handler, when the node is loaded, should the publishing option checkbox be ticked (as desired so the user can see what is set in case of changing it to untick) or would this only be triggered after having clicked submit?

Comment: @Markus No, in the second part of the answer, the tick is not checked, the status is setted to "published" in the node_presave(), if something changed in title, or body.

Comment: @Markus And the handler is called once, when the form is submitted.

Comment: I see. I wanted this option to be pre-set to save that step for the user but still allow them to be able to untick it in case they choose not to publish it, sorry if I wasn't clear with that :/ With above code it will publish even if the user doesn't want to.

Is that still possible with a custom handler?

Comment: @Markus Ok :) So, I think that you need is a mix between the two parts of the answer: 1. Use the goto with from-email (from part 2). 2. Use the form_alter to only pre-check to publish option (from part 1 with check of $_GET). 3. That's all :) - No need of the custom handler, no need of hook_node_presave().